# How to update Xcode 3.2.5 to 4.4.1 version in mac leopard?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, operating-system

Im running mac os X 10.6.8 (recent update). In which Xcode 3.2.5 has been already installed. And i like to install 4.4.1 (latest version).  but i'm getting an cross symbol over the dmg icon which doesn't allow me to install the latest version of xcode. Kindly guide me on this. Thanks.

Comment: I think the latest XCode version need Mountain Lion (1.8.0/1) to run!

Comment: @Mithrandir No, there is a version of Xcode 4.4.1 for Lion as well.

Comment: according to the Appstore: the minimum version of the OSX is the 10.7.4 for the Xcode 4.4.1. _Version: 4.4.1, Requirements: OS X 10.7.4 or later_, which is `OS X Lion`. have you installed the Lion already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Xcode 4.4.1 is not supported under Snow Leopard (Leopard is 10.5, not 10.6).  You will have to upgrade OS X to Lion or Mountain Lion or stick with [Xcode 4.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard.dmg) (Apple Developer account required).

Comment: That's the correct answer, in snow leopard you can only install up to xcode 4.2. And in a couple of days, iOS 6 will be released and I don't think they make a xcode for snow leopard supporting iOS6, so the best option is update to mountain lion or lion

Comment: But how can I do that for Macbook white since it doesnt support upgradation to Lion..